# Can the thief escape (from a smooth, simple closed curve)?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, recreational-mathematics, differential-game-theory

Let $C\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth, simple closed curve. The thief is inside $C$. Before he starts to move, the police bureau of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ world can freely place countably infinite officers on $C$. We know that

- The thief and the officers move simultaneously and continuously. Maximum speed is $1$ for everyone.
- The officers are restricted to move on $C$. They can pass right through each other without collision.
- The thief is caught if his coordinates coincide with those of an officer.

There're 3 possibilities:

1. The thief always has a plan to get out of $C$.
2. The officers always have a plan to prevent the thief from getting out.
3. It depends on the shape of $C$.

Which one is true?

---

Response to comments:

1. If $m(t)$ is a path of the thief, continuous movement means $\vert m(t)-m(s)\vert \leq \vert t-s\vert, \forall t,s$. In particular, we do not require the path to be differentiable. Similarly for an officer path $l(t)$.
2. Let $Q(t)\subset C$ be the set of officers at time $t$. The thief escapes if $\ \exists_t\,m(t)\,\in\, C\setminus Q(t)$.
3. The thief and the officers have perfect information about everybody's current position and move according to that information. For example, officer 1 may adopt a strategy like "if $\vert m_x-l_x\vert\gt 0$, move at maximum speed in the direction that decreases it, otherwise stay still".

Comment: “They move with equal speed”: what is exactly the regularity of their motion?

Comment: couldn't it also depend on where the thief and officers start?

Comment: @PietroMajer I've edited the question to address that.

Comment: @BD107 No, because the police bureau can place the officers wherever they wish. If the thief could escape no matter the officer placements from some point $p$, they can escape from any point by first heading to $p$.

Comment: What knowledge do the thief and officers have of the other's position?

Comment: I suppose both thief and police may adjust their movements, depending on the current configuration. But this seems hard to formalize. It would perhaps work better in a discrete model.

Comment: There is a whole study of games of this sort; here is a survey https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.05013 . I couldn't find a quick source to link to for a precise definition, but the definition I would try is that the robber specifies a function giving their velocity as a function of the positions of themself and the police; the police do likewise, and then the trajectories of each person are obtained by solving the resulting ODE. Of course, one has to make sure that the function is nice enough that the ODE is solvable, but maybe we can make progress without digging into the details of this?

Comment: "Countably infinite officers on " means that they can be placed densely on $C$. I guess  a dense initial placement can't be worse than any placement whose closure does not include $C$. And if they are dense I fail to see how the shape of $C$ can play a role, provided it is smooth. The thief should head for a point of $C$ where there is no officer and the game becomes a local approximation problem. In the survey mentioned by David E Speyer the pursuers are always finite, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What about 1 cop (for short) trying to catch the thief crossing a segment? If the cop moves on the segment at top speed towards the thief (provided the thief starts far enough and the cop's reaction time is 0) then they should meet. Likewise a dense set of cops on a convex curve: if they run towards the thief only when the latter is much closer to them than, say, the minimum radius of curvature, while remaining dense all the time. On a non convex curve, the thief may try to trap them in a cul de sac, but that should be thwarted by the cops remaining dense always. So my guess is 2.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: I'm not optimistic about this, as an attempt to give rigorous definitions. One would have to solve an infinite system which is about the same thing as a (non-linear) PDE, so we can't expect any existence or uniqueness results to be within reach.

Comment: This also has a slightly paradoxical feel to it because no matter what strategy the police chose, it clearly was stupid since they could have deployed an additional countable squad at no cost.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy They have perfect information about each other's current position.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch seems right --- make an answer from your comment.

Comment: I think this was sort of said already, but I am pretty sure that the "There're 3 possibilities" trichotomy makes a determinacy type assumption that typically is simply not true for this type of games

Comment: @VilleSalo What could be a fourth possibility?

Comment: @Eric Two other possibilities which I think can both happen when you consider very general games: 1) the winner of a game is not even determined for some strategies, in the sense that the behavior is a differential equation with no solution, 2) there is no winning strategy for either player, i.e. any strategy of one can be beaten by the other, by changing the strategy (non-determinacy). For 2) I don't know "this type" of example, but a standard example is the "pick the bigger number" game.

Comment: I believe that this is quite closely related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.00688.pdf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Claim.** The thief $T$ can escape if $C$ is a circle, with a simple strategy of dribbling left and right each policeman at a time in such a way that he is left out of reach of the thief no matter what the future dribbles will be.

**Proof.**
The key insight is due to Pietro Majer: the thief can approach $C$ in such a way that its shadow $S$ (closest point) on $C$ always moves at speed faster than $1$.

Assume $C$ has radius $1$ and pick a number $r$ once and for all, with $1/2<r<1$.

At any time there are exactly two circles $C_1$, $C_2$ of radius $r$, tangent to $C$ and contaning $T$. The strategy of the the thief is to always run at speed $1$, alternating between these two ways:

$-$ either move right on $C_1$ towards $A$ (dragging $C_2$ and $B$ along)

$-$ or move left on $C_2$ towards $B$ (dragging $C_1$ and $A$ along).

[image: circle]

No matter how $T$ zigzags left and right, the symmetry between $C_1$ and $C_2$ with respect to $T$ guarantees that the path followed by $T$ has the same total length $\overset{\frown}{TA}=\overset{\frown}{TB}$. Therefore $T$ will land on $C$ in finite time.

As for the shadow $S$, $r>1/2$ implies that it always moves at speed $>1$, i.e. the (infinitesimal) arc length inequality $\delta_1<\delta_2$ always holds (see figure). This is a tedious but elementary trigonometric inequality, better left to the reader.

Before detailing how the thief's zigzags are decided, we need to notice that any policeman to the right of $A$, or to the left of $B$, by *strictly more* than $\overset{\frown}{SA}$, is **inactive**, in other words he can never catch $T$, even if $T$ runs towards him all the way to $C$.

Finally, **enumerate** all the policemen $P_1, P_2, P_3 \dots$

Take the first **active** policeman on the list, say $P_{i_1}$. If $P_{i_1}$ is to the left of $S$ (or on $S$) $T$ chooses to run right towards $A$ at speed $1$. (Similarly if $P$ were to the right, $T$  would choose to run left towards $B$.) Because $S$ moves at speed $>1$ at some point $P_{i_1}$ permanently falls behind $S$ by some amount $\epsilon_1$ (it doesn't matter how small). However $P_{i_1}$ may still be within the active range, so $T$ keeps running towards $A$ until $\overset{\frown}{SA}<\epsilon_1/3$. Since $\overset{\frown}{SB}=\overset{\frown}{SA}$, now $P_{i_1}$ is behind $B$ by strictly more than $\epsilon_1/3$. This renders $P_{i_1}$ permanently inactive!

Similarly, take the next active policeman $P_{i_2}$ on the list. Again $T$ runs in the direction away from him, until $P_{i_2}$ is inactive too. There at most countably many active policemen and one by one they all become inactive, guaranteeing that $T$ lands on a police-free point of $C$.$\quad \blacksquare$

This proof should easily extend to any curve $C$, since $T$ can first move close to a point of positive curvature, where locally the curve can be approximated well by a circle.

Comment: @ChristianRemling. The definition of "inactive" uses a *strict* inequality (the word "more"), so for each policeman $P_i$ there a margin of $\epsilon_i$ that can never be closed no matter what $T$ does. Since $T$ (and $S$) clearly converge, each $P_i$ is at least $\epsilon_i$ away from their limit. Should I edit the answer to make that more clear?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it's clear to me now. I probably didn't read it carefully enough. But maybe it would help to say explicitly that the structure of the argument is that you approach a point $p$ along a path that is divided into segments, and what we do on the $n$th segment will make sure that $d(P_n,P)\ge \epsilon_n$.

Comment: By the way, I think you could also use straight line segments instead of the circular arcs, then you don't need the "tedious calculation" in item 3.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you for the thoughtful feedback. I'll edit the answer. Regarding internal segments, the problem is that their points with the property of the shadows moving faster, form subsegments that don't reach the circle. So one would need some messy pasting of infinitely many different segments and it may no longer be so easy to prove that they add up to an infinite path. The beauty of the 2 tangent circles is that because of the symmetry between left and right, the total length of the path is unaffected by the zigzagging.

Comment: How different the situation if the curve isn't smooth! For a example a thief at the center of a square enclosure is always caught by 4 cops starting at the centers of the edges, but can escape 4 cops starting at the corners.

Comment: So it seems the key to the problem is positive curvature? If the thief is initially outside the circle, do you think he can get inside it? If the enclosure has negative curvature everywhere except at finite point, a concave square for example, does the thief get out?

Comment: @Eric Yes and no, respectively. It seems that a stretch of the curve with negative or $0$ curvature (plus finitely many singularities) can be guarded by a finite number of policemen, while any stretch with positive curvature (bounded below) cannot be guarded by even a dense, countable set. The concave square would be even easier to guard than the regular flat square.

Comment: This is really nice!

Answer (score 0):

The cops should always win. Here is a sketch of a proof.

1. One cop (for short) trying to catch the thief crossing a segment: the cop can run on the segment at top speed towards the thief (provided the thief starts far enough and the cop's reaction time is 0). Clearly they will meet.
2. Likewise a dense set of cops on a convex curve $C$: they can run towards the thief only when the latter is "close" to them, while keeping dense all the time. To make this precise: let $r$ be the minimum radius of curvature, which exists because $C$ is smooth and compact; whenever the thief is closer to $C$ than $r$ there is a unique point $P\in C$ to which the thief is closest, with distance $d_P<r$; if $d\ge d_P$ is the distance of a cop from the thief, that cop should run towards $P$ at speed $\text{max}(1-d/r,0)$. This strategy is continuous on $C$ and guarantees that the cops will stay a dense set, and also approaches the strategy in 1) as the thief gets closer to $C$, guaranteeing an eventual catch.
3. This works on a non convex curve too. On a curve with a singularity the thief can try to split the cops and trap them in a cul de sac, but on a smooth curve that is thwarted by the cops remaining dense always.

**Update.** See comments for where this argument goes wrong.

Comment: But does this guarantee that one cop catches the thief? The shadow on $P$ of the thief on $C$ has possibly velocity $>1$, while each cop running after it has speed $\le1$. Can’t the thief move so smartly that he reaches $C$ at time $T$, but and at time $T-1/n$ The point $P$ has dribbled or escaped eventually  Cop_n ?

Comment: @PietroMajer You make a very good point. I don't have an answer to that.

Comment: Suppose the police bureau can freely place countably infinite officers on the x-axis, but each officer's speed is at most $1-\epsilon$. Can the thief cross over the line from one side to the other? I think he can, but I can't prove.

Comment: The speed of the shadow $P$ should be bounded by $r/(r-d_P)$, so as the thief gets closer to $C$ its ability outrun the cops decreases, but I don't see if there is a way to use that in favor of the cops. @Eric neatly nails this point with his comment.

Comment: Maybe one can modify your strategy this way. Two cops  start moving as soon the thief is has distance $r$ to the curve $C$, say $C$ is parametrised in arc length, and they are in positions $A<P<B$ with $B-A \approx  r$. Then they take care not to be passed by $P$, so that $A<P<B$ holds for all times (this means running after P when he moves away, and moving away when he gets closer).  Even if $P$ can move faster, I think $A$ and $B$ can make their distance vanish in finite time. (So at the end the principle should be, of course, the 2 policemen’s theorem)

Comment: @PietroMajer The thief doesn't even need to dribble. Assume $C$ is a circle and the thief starts from the center and approaches the boundary along a fixed spiral path which crosses the circle tangentially. He can probably modulate his speed to cross the boundary without getting caught. And perhaps he can even do that in a $C^1$ or $C^{\infty}$ way.

Comment: That would be truly amazing if true. As @PietroMajer commented, whether the officers are coded or not can make a big difference. I think if it turns out that the thief has a strategy to escape, the plan must be something like coding the officers 1,2,3,... and getting rid of the $n$th officer at time $t_n$, traveling along shortening arcs or chords that reach the boundary in finite time $T=t_{\infty}$.

Comment: @Pietro Majer: +1 for the one on the two policemen's theorem :)

Comment: @Yaakov Baruch: I don't really get this. Can you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte The problem is that the projection P has a velocity slightly larger than 1, so the thief can either avoid or pass each single cop before touching the curve, and in principle touch the curve in a point not occupied by a cop.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte If the thief approaches the boundary (a circle) along a spiral which has radius of curvature always less than that of the circle and approaches it very gently, then his shadow on the circle moves faster than 1. Perhaps he can use that (and modulating the landing point) to outpace all the countably many policemen that approach him (from either direction). How gently needs the spiral to approach? I think one can solve a differential equation to find the exact formula, but I haven't worked it out.

Comment: Ok, I see that there are more subtleties than I thought. But my feeling is that quantifiers should be better specified in the problem statement. One possibility is: everyone has perfect and instantaneous information about the others. The officers place themselves after knowing the starting point of the thief and then they must follow a countable list of strategies decided in advance and such that their motion will only depend on current position and velocity of the thief; on the other hand, the thief knows in advance all the countable strategies that officers adopt. Is this the setting?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch I think there is a strategy for the cops, such that, even if the thief is able to avoid any cop and leave him behind, this forces him to delay the arrival time, so that if he wants to avoid them all , he will never escape (in which case he looses according to rule 2). He will then rotate forever, and some cops will move towards his shadow, as soon as he passes, for a while,  in case he tries to land.

Comment: @PietroMajer I'm thinking along 2 lines, both in favor of the thief:  1) the thief could make continuous, rapidly decreasing random adjustments to his landing target to make his landing an unpredictable random point which has probability 1 of being cop-free;  2) as the thief nears $C$ and $P$ always moves at $>1$ speed, more cops fall out of the reachability radius. For the first cop (according to a predetermined numbering) that is still within that radius, the thief can exclude him out by a combination of cutting his own distance from $C$ and outrunning the cop, and so for every cop.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Please can you specify whether your strategy 2 falls within my proposed setting of the problem? As for 1, I'm a bit lost, as I don't really understand what you mean by "random point which has probability 1 of being cop-free". Even if the thief moves randomly (whatever it means), the cops are not, since they will know exactly where the thief is, so how this exactly applies?

Comment: @PietroMajer Can you describe what such a strategy of the cops might look like, say for cops on a circle for example?

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte In plan 2, yes it's irrelevant what strategies the cops use: one by one each is forever left out of reach by the thief (provided the correction the thief makes to his landing plan at each step is vanishingly smaller than the previous one, so that no already lost cop can get back within reach again). I think this may work and a simple, finite starting path that (with the corrections) does the job for a circle $C$ of radius $1$ is one tangent to $C$ on the inside, of radius $>1/2$. Plan 1 is vague: I just feel the speed $>1$ makes the thief potentially unpredictable.